# Python Reportlab insert image base64 colors are being inverted

Tags: python, base64, reportlab

I am trying to add a base64 image on a pdf using ReportLab.  I am able to add the image successfully.  However, the colors for the image are being inverted.

To confirm that it wasn't the base64 code that had the colors inverted, I manually converted the base64 online to make sure the colors were correct.

Does anyone have any clue why ReportLab .drawImage might invert the colors?

Here is my code where 'signature' is the base64 encoded image:

```
image64 = signature
p.drawImage(image64, 110, 25)
```

Here is the output on the pdf. The black block is the image that is being inverted:
[pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsxPQ.png)

Comment: Could you please add some more info on how you generated `image64`? It could be that the image uses BGR instead of RGB :)

Comment: @B8vrede I used jsignature to convert the signature to base64

Comment: I just tested it the demo of jsignature and couldn't reproduce your problem. Are you sure that PIL is installed correctly? And could you confirm that `image64` is a string referring to the location of the image?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. Can you try putting `mask='auto'` parameter?

```
image64 = signature
p.drawImage(image64, 110, 25 ,mask='auto')
```